# PHP: Add Unique ID + Order ID for each word what starts with @

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, unique

**I need to add an Order ID + Unique ID for each word what starts with `@`.**

---

For example I have a **`string`** like this:

`Just @do @it and @do @it.`

I want to **`preg_replace`** `#(\@)+([^\s]+)#i` to this:

`Just <div id="1+Unique ID">@do</div> <div id="2+Unique ID">@it</div> and <div id="3+Unique ID">@do</div> <div id="4+Unique ID">@it</div>.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `/e` flag to `preg_replace` to run code for each replacement:

```
$string = 'Just @do @it and @do @it.';
$id = 0;

echo preg_replace('/@\w+/e', '"<div id=\"".++$id."\">\\0</div>"', $string);
```

Output:

```
Just <div id="1">@do</div> <div id="2">@it</div> and <div id="3">@do</div> <div id="4">@it</div>.
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks very much it works!I can't believe you made it! I was searching for weeks for something like this!!! But could you tell me how should I use it with a `variable` so `preg_replace('/@\w+/e', $replace, $string);`

Comment: Set `$replace` to the exact string above. Make sure to use the same single and double quotes exactly as I wrote it: `$replace = '"<div id=\"".++$id."\">\\0</div>"';`